# switch between 2 classes on each click

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick, toggleclass

I am trying to work out how to change between this:

```
            <li class="menu">
```

and this:

```
            <li class="menu open">
```

on each click of the menu.  Basically so the menu opens on each click if closed and closes on each click if open

Code Snippet:

```
<div id="headerbar">
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="container">

      <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.php"><img src="./img/home_icon.png" alt="Home"></a></li>
      </ul>



      <ul>
        <li class="menu">
          <a href="#" class="menu">Menu Heading</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown">
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have read a few posts about toggleClass but cannot seem to get it working.  If someone could break it down simply for me it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a clipping from the CSS:

```
.topbar div > ul a.menu:hover,
.nav a.menu:hover,
.topbar div > ul li.open .menu,
.nav li.open .menu,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-toggle:hover,
.nav .dropdown-toggle:hover,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle,
.nav .dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown,
.nav .menu-dropdown,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu,
.nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #333;
}
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown a.menu,
.nav .menu-dropdown a.menu,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu a.menu,
.nav .dropdown-menu a.menu,
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown .dropdown-toggle,
.nav .menu-dropdown .dropdown-toggle,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle,
.nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown a.menu.open,
.nav .menu-dropdown a.menu.open,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu a.menu.open,
.nav .dropdown-menu a.menu.open,
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown .dropdown-toggle.open,
.nav .menu-dropdown .dropdown-toggle.open,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle.open,
.nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle.open {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown li a,
.nav .menu-dropdown li a,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu li a,
.nav .dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown li a:hover,
.nav .menu-dropdown li a:hover,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.nav .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #191919;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#292929),     to(#191919));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #191919);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #191919);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #292929), color-stop(100%, #191919));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #191919);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #292929, #191919);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #292929, #191919);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292929', endColorstr='#191919', GradientType=0);
  color: #ffffff;
}
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown .active a,
.nav .menu-dropdown .active a,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu .active a,
.nav .dropdown-menu .active a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.topbar div > ul .menu-dropdown .divider,
.nav .menu-dropdown .divider,
.topbar div > ul .dropdown-menu .divider,
.nav .dropdown-menu .divider {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #444;
}
.topbar ul .menu-dropdown li a, .topbar ul .dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 4px 15px;
}
li.menu, .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
a.menu:after, .dropdown-toggle:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "&darr;";
  text-indent: -99999px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #ffffff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.menu-dropdown, .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 900;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 220px;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 6px 0;
  zoom: 1;
  border-color: #999;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.menu-dropdown li, .dropdown-menu li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: none;
}
.menu-dropdown .divider, .dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.topbar .dropdown-menu a, .dropdown-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #808080;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}
.topbar .dropdown-menu a:hover,
.dropdown-menu a:hover,
.topbar .dropdown-menu a.hover,
.dropdown-menu a.hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eeeeee), to(#dddddd));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #dddddd);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #dddddd);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #eeeeee), color-stop(100%, #dddddd));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #dddddd);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #dddddd);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #dddddd);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#dddddd', GradientType=0);
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025), inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025), inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025), inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
}
.open .menu,
.dropdown.open .menu,
.open .dropdown-toggle,
.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.open .menu-dropdown,
.dropdown.open .menu-dropdown,
.open .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You've tagged your question `toggleclass` -- are you using jQuery? Why have you not tagged the question `jquery`?

Comment: Four hours from when you posted your question and no response to calls for clarification or the answers provided!  That's not cool.  I know you're knew to asking questions, but you should be reading comments and answers within an hour after posting (ideally within 15 mins after posting) to make sure your question is understood and there is no confusion about what you meant.  You can also provide feedback on the direction of the answers.  In this case, we don't know if you can or cannot use jQuery.

Comment: Apologies, I posting and went to sleep.  Did not realise how fast you guys would be!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't using jQuery and need to do this in plain javascript, then you can do it like this:

```
// function called by click to toggle class on parent
function toggleMenu(item) {
    toggleClass(item.parentNode, "open");
    return(false);    // don't do other default handling for the click
}

// utility functions for adding, removing classes
function addClass(elem, cls) {
    var oldCls = elem.className;
    if (oldCls) {
        oldCls += " ";
    }
    elem.className = oldCls + cls;
}

function removeClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    elem.className = str.replace(" " + cls + " ", "").replace(/^\s+/g, "").replace(/\s+$/g, "");
}

function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) != -1) ;
}

function toggleClass(elem, cls) {
    if (hasClass(elem, cls)) {
        removeClass(elem, cls);
    } else {
        addClass(elem, cls);
    }
}
```

And, in your HTML, I added an onclick handler to one item:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="#" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">Menu Heading</a>
    <ul class="menu-dropdown">
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Option 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2pVmF/

Comment: Thank you for the demo.  Not certain on how to implement this.  I tried putting it in <script> tags and in a separate js file but can't get it to work.  One thing I did notice is that the dropdown example you provided closed on clicking the menu options.  I added a link to 1 option but not sure if its live update?

Comment: @user1560199 - The point of my answer was to provide you with four functions including `toggleClass()` for manipulating classes on an object and demonstrate an event handler using it.  You did not disclose your entire HTML or the full problem you are trying to solve so I cannot offer you a solution to that.  You should be able to hook up your own event listeners to whatever objects you want clicks to work on and use these functions and this general technique to make your class toggle work.  I've updated my code to only process the click if it's on the parent div, not on the children.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00.  Trying to figure this out.  I have updated my html and CSS it thy offer any more information.  Not very familiar with how js works so please forgive the lack of detail.  I managed to get it changing onclick with some inline code - but was very basic and didnt close again, only opened - I think I was thinking this was going to be a simple half a line of inline code - Thanks!

Comment: @n00bstacker - I've modified my answer and the jsFiddle to use your HTML and your CSS and you can see it work now.

Comment: Brilliant!! - Thanks jfriend00!  Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question `toggleclass`, which is a jQuery-specific tag. Assuming you're really using jQuery, then it's a trivial application of a [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click) handler and [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass):

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    // Toggle the class
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

If you want to do anything further, other than just toggling the class:

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // Toggle the class
    $this.toggleClass("open");

    // Further work
    if ($this.hasClass("open")) {
        // The menu is now open, do stuff related to that...
    }
    else {
        // The menu is now closed, do stuff related to that...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with modern browsers that supports [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList), you can simple have:

```
 element.classList.toggle("open");
```

Where `element` is the reference to the element you want to "toggle" the css class. However, `jQuery` and libraries like that are more indicated for this kind of operations, especially in combination with event listeners.

Answer (score -1):

If using jquery use

```
$(".menu").addClass("open");  
$(".menu").removeClass("open");
```